# Como ejecutar procedimiento después de carga de datos en una tabla

Tags: trigger

Hola tengo 2 tablas A y B. Debo cargar 600 mil registros en B y luego copiar algunas columnas de B en A a través de un procedimiento almacenado(ya creado). ¿Cómo haría para que se ejecute el procedimiento de copia de datos hacia A cuando finalice la carga de los 600 mil datos en B?. Se que puedo ejecutar procedimientos a través de un trigger con cualquier campo que se modifique o actualice en una tabla, pero en este caso no actualizo ningún campo sino que cargo datos en toda la tabla B.

Agradecería la orientación de la comunidad sobre este caso.

Saludos y quedo atento.

Comment: ¿Qué entiendes tú por *cargar datos*? Conviene que hables en términos del lenguaje SQL. Si te refieres a *insertar datos* entonces existen TRIGGER del tipo `AFTER INSERT` que podrías usar en este caso.

Comment: Hola A. Cedano. Cuando hablo de cargar datos, es hacer una importación de 600 mil registros sobre la tabla B desde una hoja de excel. luego de que se haga la importación de esos 600 mil registros, quiero ejecutar un procedimiento almacenado que ya existe. Mi pregunta es como hago para que se ejecute un procedimiento almacenado después de haber terminado de importar los 600 mil registros.

Comment: *Mi pregunta es como hago para que se ejecute un procedimiento almacenado después de haber terminado de importar los 600 mil registros.* Pues llama a ese procedimiento almacenado en la línea siguiente al código desde el cual lanzas la importanción de esos 600 mil registros. Supongo que retornarás algo (`true` por ejemplo) una vez la importanción haya terminado para verificar que no ha habido ningún problema.